# how to show files in angular 8

Tags: angular, file, viewer

I want to display the files, with different extensions in the Angular component.
What modules do I use for this?
I have reviewed the following modules.But each has a problem.

- ngx-doc-viewer: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-doc-viewer
- ngx-extended-pdf-viewer: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer
- WebViewer: https://www.pdftron.com/webviewer/demo/

Comment: You can't access the file system from the browser. Your server can access the file system, and you can serve up whatever file information you want from your server to your Angular app

Answer (score 1):

you can use **angular-file-viewer**

this package support PDF, JPEG, PNG, MP4

[Demo](https://taldor-ltd.github.io/angular-file-viewer/)

**install**

```
npm i @taldor-ltd/angular-file-viewer ng2-pdf-viewer
```

**Usage**

Add AngularFileViewerModule to your module's imports

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AngularFileViewerModule } from '@taldor-ltd/angular-file-viewer';

import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';

 @NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, AngularFileViewerModule],
 declarations: [AppComponent],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
 })

 class AppModule {}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

And then use it in your component

(PDF sample)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { FileMimeType } from '@taldor-ltd/angular-file-viewer';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
template: `
<tld-file-viewer [src]="src" [type]="type"></tld-file-viewer>`

})
export class AppComponent {
src = 'http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf';
 type = FileMimeType.PDF;
}
```

[documentation](https://github.com/taldor-ltd/angular-file-viewer)